# What's with philosophers and their use of quotation marks?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, semantics, language, linguistics, syntax

I'm reading Hofstadter and Quine at the same time and this is deep.

---

An explanation:

The logician's use of "quotations" in sentences like this one would suggest that a quoted phrase is essentially a noun. Nouns are names for things, and the thing being named by "the quoted phrase" seems to be the quoted phrase itself.

Now I would like to think "it's as simple as that - quotation marks turn arbitrary strings into nouns," and be done with it. However, as demonstrated by the preceding sentence, it's not quite that simple. After all "Now I would like to think that <noun>, and be done with it." is hardly a complete sentence.

Perhaps I need to make some finer distinction between different sorts of quotation - say that which acts as a pointer and that which references a speaker? Of course, this touches on the broader issue of the syntax/semantics distinction being wholly artificial outside of contexts specifically constructed to preserve it (namely linguistics and computer science textbooks) since a quoted phrase has no way of "knowing" whether it is being used to refer to words conveyed by some sentient messenger or a literal substring of "meaningless" text. Whatever the case, the use of quotes doesn't fit cleanly into what I already know about language, so I need to figure out how make room for it.

**What's up with the use of quotation marks in philosophy?**

Comment: Please add an explanation. Grammatically, a direct quote is typically the direct object of a sentence. Is that what Hofstadter and Quine wanted to know?

Comment: Are you sure that you concerned with the part of speech? That seems to be merely a grammatical question. For Quine, quoted expressions may have truth values, and by the disquotational account of truth we can understand their logic by disquoting them.

Comment: Simple example: Napoleon is an emperor vs "Napoleon" is a name. Can you see the difference?

Answer (score 2):

### Short Answer

Quotation marks are tricky things, and they can be used in a number of ways. In philosophy, there are several ways that come to mind that philosophers rely on beyond an actual quotation and attribution of text, though it's not as if some of these aren't used outside of philosophy. Let's take a quick look.

#### Scare Quotes

The first and most familiar is [scare quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scare_quotes), a term apparently coined by [Elizabeth Anscombe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G._E._M._Anscombe) herself. Simply put, words have standard meanings, the type understood from convention, and an author can indicate a deviation of conventional [connotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connotation) and [denotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denotation) such as irony or skepticism.

> **Bob the Skeptic:** *texts friend* What are doing with your car engine?
> **Bill the Ambitious:** *responds with phone* I'm fixing it. I'm sort of a mechanic.
> **Bob the Skeptic:** *sends rolls-eyes emoji* Yes, Bill, you're quite the "mechanic", alright. Remember when you put the motor oil in the master brake cylinder?
> **Bill the Ambitious:** Ha, ha, Bob. Not gonna let me live that one down, eh?

In philosophy, a variety of attitudes can be conveyed by authors who find it in their interest to call attention to a word because it is somehow important in an argument and convey skepticism, doubt, uncertainty and so on.

#### Neologisms and Terminology

Frequently, philosophers stretch their natural language by coining new terms. After all, 10,000 years ago, there was no vocabulary for many concepts we take for granted on a day. As we have seen, "scare quotes" was a term coined by Anscombe. "Transcendental idealism" is a term that refers to [this philosophy by Immanuel Kant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_idealism). Sometimes when word-smithing, it helps to draw attention to the [neologism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neologism) by the use of quotation marks, though, not necessary strictly speaking. The same can be done in a passage when conveying a [term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminology) which, while not a neologism, is unfamiliar to a student or reader; in modern textbooks, bold and italicized typefaces also may carry out this function.

#### Use-Mention Distinction

The [use-mention distinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction) is particularly important to philosophers because it distinguishes the identifier from that which it identifies which can be a source of confusion. From WP:

> The use–mention distinction is a foundational concept of analytic philosophy, according to which it is necessary to make a distinction between using a word (or phrase) and mentioning it. Many philosophical works have been "vitiated by a failure to distinguish use and mention". The distinction can sometimes be pedantic, especially in simple cases where it is obvious.
>
> The distinction between use and mention can be illustrated with the word cheese:
>
> Use: Cheese is derived from milk.
> Mention: 'Cheese' is derived from the Old English word ċēse.

To get a taste of how failure to heed the difference can have a comical effect, watch [this video of Daniel Dennett talking about the difference between love and "love" (YT)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1EuhcxZs1qg). The use of quotation marks for neologisms above can be seen as a frequent use of the use-mention distinction. Note his use of [air quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_quotes).

#### Strings as Abstractions

In [analytical philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_philosophy), especially since the [linguistic turn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_turn), the focus on the [philosophy of language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_language) is evident. One place where philosophers in particular place a lot of emphasis is on the [philosophies of mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_mathematics) and [computer science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_computer_science). In these fields, the abstraction known as the [string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_(computer_science)) is of supreme importance. Strings are nothing more than sequences of characters, which from a linguistics perspective, are standardized [graphemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapheme) such as the US standard known as [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). Strings and quotation marks are also important in the study of [metasyntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntax) and [metalanguages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalanguage). From WP:

> In logic and linguistics, a metalanguage is a language used to describe another language, often called the object language. Expressions in a metalanguage are often distinguished from those in the object language by the use of italics, quotation marks, or writing on a separate line.

The structure of sentences and phrases in a metalanguage can be described by a metasyntax. This can get particularly hairy and confusing when [nested quotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_quotation) are used for [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion). For example:

> **Hard:** Bob said "I'm going to the tell Bill that Mary said "Why don't you remember the Ancient Greeks and their adage "Temet nosce!"?"".
> **Easier:** Bob said "I'm going to the tell Bill that Mary said 'Why don't you remember the Ancient Greeks and their adage *Temet Nosce*'".

#### The Disquotational Principle and Theory of Truth

Lastly, when examining meta- and object languages, one can also make claims about the relation between an [agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agency_(philosophy)) and their [propositional attitudes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_attitude), or an [utterance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utterance) and a [truth-condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth-conditional_semantics), and express the thought using quotation marks. In the case of the [disquotational principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disquotational_principle):

> The disquotational principle is a philosophical principle which holds that a rational speaker will accept "p" if and only if he or she believes p. The quotes indicate that the statement p is being treated as a sentence, and not as a proposition. This principle is presupposed by claims that hold that substitution fails in certain intensional contexts.

And [disquotational theory of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redundancy_theory_of_truth) uses the quotation marks similarly:

> According to the redundancy theory of truth (also known as the disquotational theory of truth), asserting that a statement is true is completely equivalent to asserting the statement itself. For example, asserting the sentence "'Snow is white' is true" is equivalent to asserting the sentence "Snow is white". The philosophical redundancy theory of truth is a deflationary theory of truth.

These are a little more complicated, so I won't go into the details.

#### Conclusion

Strings delimited by quotation marks in philosophy straddle several categories. What is important to understand is that they are tremendously impactful for navigating [syntax and semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax%E2%80%93semantics_interface). Besides actual quotations, quotation marks can be used in several circumstances to express alternative meanings, relations, or draw attention to text.

Comment: Let me know if there are any specific cases I missed. I'm just working from memory.